# Asterisk (version 16) Redirect action does not complete 1st leg of call

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-java

After redirect action sent to Asterisk AMI, first leg of call is not completed until 2 leg of  call completed, 1 leg completes as well at the same time with 2nd leg. This forces first sip member to be hang up for a some period of time not static though
/n
Asterisk v 16
Asterisk-java lib version = 3.0.0 SNAP-shot

org.asteriskjava.manager.action.RedirectAction[action='Redirect',extraexten='null',extrapriority='null',context='queue',channel='SIP/8227-00000003',actionid='null',extrachannel='null',extracontext='null',priority='1',exten='78888*',systemHashcode=1972526562]

Comment: P.S: Im not sure why issue down voted. Could you clarify what i have done wrong?Is it title or format ? content? Duplicate question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect will do only legs you specified.

If you want hangup second leg - send it via extrachannel/extracontext to hangup extension.

Comment: Actually it worked.In an old version (we used asterisk 11) of asterisk this issue handled by itself. So was confused what could be reason.Thanks for help friend